# postgresql / plpgsql - function with a loop and multiple actions

Tags: sql, postgresql, plpgsql

I'm fairly new to Postgres but I've created a function via pgAdmin 4.15, Postgres is at version 9.6.
Problem is I can't make it work, I think there is something wrong in the syntax?
INSERT and UPDATE statements are working (outside the function), so it must be the function syntax...

The intention is to call this function via a jdbc plugin (Logstash) and update some tables using the given "input" string as key.
The "key" is used to SELECT the alarm IDs to operate on.
So, for every id I get, I need to perform some UPDATE/INSERT on those tables.

```
# \sf close_event
CREATE OR REPLACE FUNCTION public.close(input text)
 RETURNS void
 LANGUAGE plpgsql
AS $function$
DECLARE
  _event_idnumber INTEGER;
BEGIN
  FOR _event_idnumber IN
    SELECT id FROM public.alerts WHERE data ->> 'field_name' = input
  LOOP
    INSERT INTO public.comments ( created_date, content, alert_id, user_id) VALUES (current_timestamp, 'text1 text', _event_idnumber, 1);
    INSERT INTO public.comments ( created_date, content, alert_id, user_id) VALUES (current_timestamp, 'text2 text.', _event_idnumber, 1);
    INSERT INTO public.analysis ( alert_id, created_date, last_updated, notes) VALUES (_event_idnumber, current_timestamp, current_timestamp, 'text3 text');
    UPDATE public.alerts SET status='DONE', outcome='completed', last_updated=current_timestamp, assigned_user_id=1 WHERE id = _event_idnumber;
    UPDATE public.alerts SET data = jsonb_set(data, '{other_field}'::text[], input::jsonb) WHERE id = _event_idnumber;
  END LOOP;
  COMMIT;
EXCEPTION
  WHEN OTHERS THEN
END;
$function$;
```

I've read that with some versions of postgres I must use a DO statement, but can't figure out how.
I'm following instructions at this page: https://www.postgresql.org/docs/9.6/plpgsql-control-structures.html

Comment: Yo don't need a loop or a function for that

Comment: You'll also need to be more specific about what you're trying to accomplish. The code will only tell us what you've implemented, not what you intended.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Because SQL is a set-based language for straightforward, logical actions you should handle your append and updates in sets and not iterative loop calls as commented. Therefore, convert the procedural language, `plpgsql` to pure `sql`. Specifically, consider select inserts with `UNION` and combining the update statements.

```
CREATE OR REPLACE FUNCTION public.close(input text)
 RETURNS void
 LANGUAGE sql
AS $function$

   -- COMMENTS INSERT
   INSERT INTO public.comments (created_date, content, alert_id, user_id) 
   SELECT current_timestamp, 'text1 text', a.id, 1
   FROM public.alerts a
   WHERE a.data ->> 'field_name' = input

   UNION ALL

   SELECT current_timestamp, 'text2 text.', a.id, 1
   FROM public.alerts a
   WHERE a.data ->> 'field_name' = input;

   -- ANALYSIS INSERT
   INSERT INTO public.analysis (alert_id, created_date, last_updated, notes) 
   SELECT a.id, current_timestamp, current_timestamp, 'text3 text'
   FROM public.alerts a
   WHERE a.data ->> 'field_name' = input;

   -- ALERTS UPDATE
   UPDATE public.alerts a
   SET status='DONE', 
       outcome='completed', 
       last_updated=current_timestamp, 
       assigned_user_id=1,
       data = jsonb_set(data, '{other_field}'::text[], input::jsonb) 
   WHERE a.data ->> 'field_name' = input;

$function$;
```

<kbd>[Online demo](https://rextester.com/MZNV74982)</kbd> *(using the 40 `'postgres'` rows in random `mydata` table)*

Comment: Yes! Thanks! Your solution is perfect, I've changed only the last update for `data` column in `data = jsonb_set(data, '{other_field}'::text[], to_json(input::text)::jsonb)` because it needs a json string.

Comment: Excellent to hear and glad to help! Happy coding!